# Using Yii2's default messages

Tags: internationalization, yii2

I can't figure out, how to use Yii's default messages, without overwriting them with the *message command*.

I have 2 translation categories: **app**, **data**.

I'd like to use the default messages, like *"Are you sure you want to delete this item?"* and *"(not set)"* from the Yii2 core, but if I use `Yii::t('yii', 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?')` and then run the `yii message` command, it creates a *yii.php* file in the messages folder with this token.

Part of my config:

```
    'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'app*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '@app/messages',
            ],
            'data*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '@app/messages',
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

How should I set up my config to use the built in texts and not to overwrite them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything. The `yii`-category is [automatically defined](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/i18n/I18N.php#L58) as soon as you use translation and it points to the messages in the framework.

That it creates an empty file is for 'yii' is normal, because you actually use that category in your code. This is unrelated to where the messages will be loaded from during normal execution.

Just make sure that you configure your apps' `language` and `sourceLanguage` correctly if not already done.